# Xorg - lightdm - multiple process

Tags: xorg, lightdm

I just want to know if is normal have multiple process(with root user) for lightdm and xorg, I am using ubuntu 16 desktop on a acer laptop with a second monitor via hdmi. 8gb ram, intel i5.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks normal to me. If in doubt, you may compare with process list in Htop that I have filtered with `lightdm` keyword on my 32-bit and 64-bit systems.

On Xubuntu 16.04 32-bit system:

```
  PID USER      PRI  NI S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
 1245 root       20   0 S  0.0  0.6  0:00.03 ├─ /usr/sbin/lightdm
 1324 root       20   0 S  0.0  0.7  0:00.02 │  ├─ lightdm --session-child 12 15
 1330 root       20   0 S  0.0  0.7  0:00.00 │  │  ├─ lightdm --session-child 12
 1329 root       20   0 S  0.0  0.7  0:00.00 │  │  └─ lightdm --session-child 12
 1264 root       20   0 S  0.0  2.2  0:10.38 │  ├─ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -
 1254 root       20   0 S  0.0  0.6  0:00.00 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/lightdm 
 1252 root       20   0 S  0.0  0.6  0:00.00 │  └─ /usr/sbin/lightdm
```

On Xubuntu 16.04 64-bit system:

```
  PID USER      PRI  NI S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
  811 root       20   0 S  0.0  0.5  0:00.05 ├─ /usr/sbin/lightdm
 1022 root       20   0 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.03 │  ├─ lightdm --session-child 12 19
 1026 root       20   0 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.00 │  │  ├─ lightdm --session-child 12
 1025 root       20   0 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.00 │  │  └─ lightdm --session-child 12
  839 root       20   0 S  0.7  1.6  0:01.34 │  ├─ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -
  876 root       20   0 S  0.0  1.6  0:00.02 │  │  └─ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :
  833 root       20   0 S  0.0  0.5  0:00.01 │  ├─ /usr/sbin/lightdm 
  831 root       20   0 S  0.0  0.5  0:00.00 │  └─ /usr/sbin/lightdm
```

Note that the "Command" field has some text cut-off at certain width because I have copied the output from Terminal without maximizing the window.

For the program `lightdm` on the same release of Xubuntu, the 64-bit system has relatively more processes than the 32-bit system counterpart (8 against 7 processes).